# how can I set up a cloudwatch alarms so that it only notifies once per day if alarm notification already sent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have set up some cloudwatch alarms using the cli [put-metric-alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html) and all works fine. The only issue is it continues to keep sending notifications (every 5 mins) which can really clog up your inbox. Is there a way that I can prevent it from sending further notifications if an Alarm notification has already been sent for the day unless a state change has occurred?.

Here is the command I am using to create the Alarm:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm --region xx-region-x
   --alarm-name 'my CPU Check' 
   --alarm-description 'my - CPU usage' 
   --namespace AWS/EC2 
   --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-xxxxxxxx 
   --metric-name CPUUtilization 
   --statistic Average 
   --comparison-operator GreaterThanThreshold 
   --unit Percent 
   --period 60 
   --threshold 0 
   --evaluation-periods 3 
   --alarm-actions arn:aws:sns:xx-region-x:xxxxxxxxxxxx:my-topic
```

Comment: It should only be sending notifications when the state changes. Perhaps you need to include your CloudWatch alarm settings in your question.

Comment: @MarkB I have updated to include the command, is it possible that the reason I am still getting notifications is because I have the threshold set to 0 (this was just for test purposes)

Comment: CloudWatch Alarms fire whenever the condition is met. If the condition is no longer met they flip back and can fire again. A treshold of > 0% CPU usage doesn't make a lot of sense. This will fire quiet often :)

Comment: @hellomichibye so the notification will always fire even if status has not changed?

Comment: @jonnie no. They will fire as soon as the condition is met. Then nothing happens until the condition is no longer met.

Comment: @hellomichibye so why in my case am I getting 500+ email notifications when nothing has changed since first notification?

Comment: @jonnie go to CloudWatch in the Management Console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home#alarm:alarmFilter=ANY and then click on your alarm. At the bottom you will see details and a History tab. Click on History.